# In an array of strings combining digits and non-digits, extract non-digit substring followed by digit substring in R

Tags: r

I have an array of strings of variable length including both non-digits and digits:

a<-c("asd asd 11 ff","qwe 1","asd qweee 33 33 ff")

I need to extract the non-digit sub-string from each element before the first digit using r:

"asd asd","qwe","asd qweee"

So far, I have tried this, but does the extraction based on the number of spaces, which does not really address my question:

paste(strsplit(a," ")[[1]][1:2],collapse = " ")

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

We can use `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(a, whitespace = "\\s+\\d+.*")
[1] "asd asd"   "qwe"       "asd qweee"
```

Or with `sub`

```
sub("\\s+\\d+.*", "", a)
```